# Getting correct call stacks in VS Concurrency profiler

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, profiler

I'm using the VS Concurrency profiler to profile a WPF application, but I can't get symbols for NGen'ned images like PresentationCore et al, so my call stacks all look like:

[image]

Is there a way to make VS do the right thing here? **Edit:** I have correctly configured my symbol paths, that's not the issue.

Comment: Good call, but I'm getting symbols for some of the system DLLs, it's only these .ni.* DLLs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured this one out - if you follow the steps [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/29/how-to-disable-optimizations-when-debugging-reference-source.aspx), it works out pretty well. Here's the short version:

1. Start an elevated CMD prompt
2. `set COMPLUS_ZapDisable=1`
3. `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\ide\devenv.exe"`
4. Go into your csproj settings, Debug Tab, and Disable the VS Hosting Process
5. Kick off the profiler - your app will be a fair bit slower because you're not using the NGen DLLs but it'll still be proportionally accurate in the profile result.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the correct way of getting this information.  It is a known annoyance and something we are looking into solving.

Comment: Teheheheh Paul :) That's -exactly- what I though, when I read that ... so I even clicked over to his SO profile .. which he/she says he does :)

Comment: Yes 'he' does :)  The offer of working in the performance domain was just to much to pass up.  I do however not use this ID internally ;)

Comment: @linuxuser27 Just giving you a hard time :)